# Почему при убирании курсора фотка не помещается обратно вниз?

Tags: jquery, javascript

Вот код:

```
$('#layer1').hover(
    function() {
        $(this).animate({
            'top' : '+20px'
        })
    },
    function() {
        $('#layer1').animate({
            'top' : '-20px'
        })
    }
);
```

При наведении `top : +20;` А при убирании, думаю, `top : -20;` Но почему то не срабатывает. Почему???

Comment: px там не нужен кстати.

Answer (score 1):

Не нужно указывать размерность:

```
$('#layer1').hover(function (evt){
   $(this).animate({ top: (evt.type == 'mouseenter' ? 20 :-20) });
});
```

Comment: При += он будет каждый раз при наведении +20 делать. Мне это не нужно @RubaXa

Comment: Ну окей, если вам нужно просто +/-20, то так и напишите, обновил комент

Comment: эффект не тот. Он поднимается 2 раза, а потом реагирует, уже 1 раз поднявшись

Comment: .stop() сделайте перед каждым .animate()

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/q4Rkk/ вот смотрите

Comment: Не знаю на сколько правильно понял вашу задачу, но возможно вы хотели этого: http://jsfiddle.net/q4Rkk/1/

Comment: Вы задачу опишите для начало.

Comment: Вы правильно поняли задачу. Однако спроектировали не так, как надо. Она некорректно работает. Побалуйтесь курсором над ним, увидите. Он смещается как вниз, так и вверх по границам.

Comment: Да я не понимаю, что за эффект вы хотите сделать и с какой целью. http://jsfiddle.net/DKN6F/ — вот пример просмотр картинок, при наведении на которые изображение будет смещаться, открывая  доп. информацию

Comment: @RubaXa в вашем случае надо делать [finish()](http://jsfiddle.net/oceog/q4Rkk/2/) т.к. stop() просто очищает очередь и незаконченная анимация будет остановлена посередине, а так как у вас относительное смещение, картинка может сползти. stop можно делать только при абсолютных значениях. я бы вообще использовал margin вместо top: http://jsfiddle.net/oceog/q4Rkk/3/